# Turn off auto-add of subroutines in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My project is built in VB.Net

Many times I find that Visual Studio has added subroutines to my code files even if a subroutine of the exact same name already exists.  This can cause debugging nightmares as the new empty routine seems to override the correct routine.  I think this can happen if I double-click on a control in the form Design view, but I try not to do this.

Is there any way to turn this off?

Example:

Hand entered

```
Private Sub TS_Main_View_Network_Click Handles TS_Main_View_Network.Click
```

System added:

```
Private Sub TS_Main_View_Network_Click( ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TS_Main_View_Network.Click
```

I guess that the system adds the second routine because the argument list (which is unneeded but may be required) list is missing from the first routine.

Comment: How does the code compile with two *methods* with the same name?

Comment: I have no idea why this is not an error(I am new to Visual Studio) but I have one example in front of me right now and is not flagged as an error.

 Main.vb(325):    Private Sub TS_Main_View_Network_Click Handles TS_Main_View_Network.Click
 Main.vb(348):    Private Sub TS_Main_View_Network_Click( ByVal sender As System.Object,  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TS_Main_View_Network.Click

I assumed one overrode the other (???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you gave in the comments the methods are [overloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybxdk47f(VS.100).aspx).

I assume you added the first one by hand because the signature is not correct for an event handler. .NET event handlers should have a signature that matches [void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx).

```
Private Sub TS_Main_View_Network_Click Handles TS_Main_View_Network.Click

Private Sub TS_Main_View_Network_Click( ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TS_Main_View_Network.Click
```

When Visual Studio adds an event handler on double click (which you can't disable out-of-the-box) it always creates a method with the correct signature.

Actually, your code takes advantage of some VB features (late-binding, perhaps) to let your declare an event handler without arguments. You cannot do that in a purely static-typed language, like C#, because it is not valid [IL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tkafs1(VS.71).aspx): the method without arguments cannot be assigned to an `EventHandler` delegate (the type of the `Click` event). Behind the scenes the VB compiler creates some sort of adapter for the method with no arguments.

Comment: Why do I need 

( ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

I am not using the event arguements?

Everything seems to work without the argument list and it certainly is easier to read

Comment: For your use case you may not need the arguments, but some times you do need them. I'll clarify this in the answer.

Comment: Of course, I keep the arguments when I need them, but for most of my cases I don't need them.

Comment: You can't disable that behavior out of the box. It might be that an extension could do that, but I am not aware of anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you write a handler for a control that does not exist, then add the control to the form in design mode, and then double click on that control.